Cannot find native module 'ExpoLocation', js engine: hermes
I'm trying to import the expo-location in my react-native app with expo.
I installed the library with this command:
npx expo install expo-location

And importing it:
import * as Location from 'expo-location'


but as soon as I add the import, the app breaks with the following error:
Error: Cannot find native module 'ExpoLocation', js engine: hermes [Component Stack]

My app.json file has
 "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-location",
        {
          "locationAlwaysAndWhenInUsePermission": "Allow this app to use your location."
        }
      ],


Did you find a solution to this? I'm seeing the same problem.

you need to rebuild the project
eas build --profile development --platform android

more info here: https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/
